# How to remove onclick="return false;" from anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got issue when i click on anchor tag it's not click, when i inspect the anchor tag then i saw it's enter onclick="return false;" please help me how to fix that. Becuase i also didn't know the which function used in this anchor tag

This is my code

```
   <li class="parent">
<a href="Go.html" onclick="return false;">
    About
</a>
<ul>
    <li class="child">
        <a href="About.html" title="About">
            About
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
        <a href="service.html" title="Staff">
            Service
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
        <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">
            Contact
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to run script with that result

```
 <li class="parent">
<a href="Go.html">
    About
</a>
<ul>
    <li class="child">
        <a href="About.html" title="About">
            About
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
        <a href="service.html" title="Staff">
            Service
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
        <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">
            Contact
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then clickable working please help me to solved this thanks

Comment: Do you not have access to the source? Just delete it from the HTML.

Comment: yes i didn't access the html

Comment: i want from jquery to fix it. thanks

Comment: Please, research: http://api.jquery.com/off/  and  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Just use `$('a[onclick]').removeAttr('onclick');`;